# Can I replace the test condition of a <c:if> with a custom tag?

Tags: jsp, el, taglib

Is there a way to replace:

```
<c:if test="${myBean.property}">
</c:if>
```

with a more web-designer-friendly tag?

Even this would be a good start:

```
<c:if test="<mylib:myProp />">
</c:if>
```

So that (almost) everything can be done with custom tags?

Comment: Why don't you like <c:if>?

Comment: It's not me :-) It's that I need to work with web designers that know nothing about JSP's, EL, and all that stuff. Since they already need to use custom taglibs, I'd like to at least not make them use EL. Any other simplification effor would be appreciated, of course.